# Cpanel to AWS migration image issue

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, gd, cpanel

I'm about to migrate a WordPress installation from Cpanel to AWS. After moved every file image files are behaving strangely!

```
Current live : http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_4763_colage-3-e1465995650514.jpg
Same image in AWS : http://**.**.***.173/example/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_4763_colage-3-e1465995650514.jpg
```

I'm confused why the image is acting like this! Any suggestions for a fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Becoz http://52.210.136.173/Thoughtonomy hits your absolute path for image.. Mean image src takes absolute link http://52.210.136.173/Thoughtonomy rather then  http://thoughtonomy.com